# Can we 'see' a fast radioactive decay live (as a spectacle)?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, visualization

What I mean is that are there any elements which we can actually observe decaying into other elements, like a magical transmutation? Just like how a paper burns into ash.(or some other interesting chemical reaction)

If yes, then please tell me about them.

Comment: There are plenty of nuclei with very short half life. We use some of them in medicine as diagnostics, e.g. to perform positron emission tomography, in which case we are actually watching them decay. Tritium is being used in watches to illuminate dials (or at least it used to be). Not sure what is supposed to be "magical" about a radioactive decay, though.

Comment: Obtaining a sample of a short-lived isotope isn't easy. If it's half-life is measured in minutes, then it's practically all going to be gone within tens of minutes of its creation. In order to obtain a sample of any short-lived isotope, it must be chemically separated from the decay products of some longer-lived isotope. There are a handful of short-lived isotopes for which you can (with the appropriate license) obtain a pre-packaged, miniature chemical laboratory, that extracts the material as its parent isotope decays: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radionuclide_generator

Answer (score 2):

Fire can burn you. Nuclear reactions are roughly a million times more energetic. So, if you could make a macroscopic radioactive object with a short enough half life to watch it burn like paper, the explosion and radiation would kill you before you had a chance to see anything.